# Develop CRUD screens for entire database schema

Tags: c#, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have around 120 tables in a database schema, the business requirement is to create a user interface for all of the tables using latest top notch (free) technologies like C#, AngularJS, bootstarp etc etc. Instead of creating/coding for 120 screens is there way to do this using user control method/way? I mean I just need to input table name and page should generate a Grid dynamically based on input/table given.

Hope I am clear about what I am looking for. If not please do let me know.

Comment: search for lightswitch, maybe it will be usefull for you?

Comment: lightswitch is also a very good option.  Probably microsoft's replacement for Access in the future.  We can only hope.....

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if this helps you: [CRUD operation with Entity Framework 6 Database First using MVC 5](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/869553/CRUD-operation-with-Entity-Framework-Database-Fi).

What this will allow you to do is scaffold out all of your CRUD screens for each table (which EF generates a model for).  It won't be the prettiest layout necessarily, but you can make it better looking later on.  At the least it'll generate all of the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:
- Generate an Entity Framework model from your database
- Create an ASP.NET Dynamic Data project
- Have your Dynamic Data context use the Entity Framework context

Dynamic Data offers CRUD interfaces for all your entities, plus you can customize their display